# How to address SQL Server query error: "Divide by zero error encountered."

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I am working on some SQL query but it's throwing an error:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

I believe this part is causing this problem:

```
(SUM(DATEDIFF(day, ce.VISITDATE, ce.TODATE))) AS [Total Working Days],
(SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME))) AS [Total Working Hours],
((COUNT(*) / SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME))) * 100)  AS [Face to Face Ratio]
```

I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: If you are getting divide by zero then your query must be wrong. We can only guess at what query might be right. *If Total Working Hours is 0, what do you want to return for Face to Face Ratio?* There's no way the accepted answer of using 1 for the SUM results in a sensible value. If it actually makes sense for Total Working Hours to be zero then it still doesn't make sense to try to report a Face to Face Ratio because there isn't one. Often NULL is used to show there is no value defined for an expression. But maybe you want to report the Face to Face Ratio Reciprocal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use CASE to check zero in the division section, and I think you want to get a result even if the SUM part returns zero value:

```
((count(*) / CASE WHEN SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME)) = 0
                  THEN 1 
                  ELSE SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME)) END) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the problem is in this line:

```
((count(*) / SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME))) * 100)  AS [Face to Face Ratio]
```

The simple solution is to use `NULLIF()`:

```
count(*) / NULLIF(SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME)), 0) * 100  AS [Face to Face Ratio]
```

This will return `NULL` instead of an error.

I should note that you might want decimal division instead of integer division.  If so:

```
count(*) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, ce.STARTTIME, ce.ENDTIME)), 0)  AS [Face to Face Ratio]
```

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff there's an:   Incorrect syntax near ')'.